# Facebook login dialog not working in IE10 mobile

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am new to facebook development. I have a mobile app that I need to connect to facebook. I am using Facebook JavaScript SDK to do the authentication. Well its working fine on desktop browsers and chrome mobile, but when I try to run my app on IE10 mobile the app is redirected to "m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=....." and it says 'IE mobile doesn't sopport this feature.Please use a different browser'. It is happening only if I am not already logged in to facebook on my mobile. If already logged in redirection is properly done. Below is my code

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function () {
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
                   channelUrl: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'l', // Channel File
                    status: true, // check login status
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
                });

                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                             $('#fb_connect').text('Disconnect').trigger("updatelayout");
                    } 
                    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                        //do something
                                               } 
                        else {                      
                        alert('not connected, click connect button to login')

                    }
                });
            $('#fb_connect').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        $('#fb_connect').text('Disconnect').trigger( "updatelayout" );

                    } else {
                        // The person cancelled the login dialog
                    }
                });
```

Help much needed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue when debugging, The problem was a security-property that has to be changed in the IE:
Internet options-> Security-> then check-box on the bottom "Enable Protect mode" has to be enabled then it will work.